# How to test proximity to the outline of a QGraphicsPathItem?

Tags: qt, geometry, drawing, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to test whether a given point `(x, y)` is located on or close to the *outline* of a `QGraphicsPathItem`.

Using [`QGraphicsItem.contains()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicspathitem.html#contains) or [`.collidesWithItem() / Path()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#collidesWithPath) will not do: those also return True if the point is contained within the area on the interior of the path, while I want to test only for points on the outline. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the question I found the following solution:

```
    path = QPainterPath(...)   # Path we are testing against
    point = QPointF(...)       # Current position

    stroker = QPainterPathStroker()
    stroker.setWidth(10)        # Distance which we consider "on" the path 
    stroke = stroker.createStroke(path)

    if stroke.contains(point):
        # point is on path
```